# Model spec is failing due to order of declarations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm running ruby 2.0.0 & Rails 4.0.2

I have a model that looks like:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :beneficiaries, -> {includes([:beneficiary_type, :gender])}

    def number_of_beneficiaries(gender, type)
        number = 0

        beneficiaries.each do |b|
            number = b.quantity  if b.gender.name == gender && b.beneficiary_type.name == type
        end

        number
    end
end
```

The spec for the model that fails looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Activity do
  it "return number of beneficiaries by gender and type" do
    beneficiary_1 = Beneficiary.new(:quantity => 15, :gender => Gender.find_by_name('hombres'), :beneficiary_type => BeneficiaryType.find_by_name('adultos'))
    beneficiary_2 = Beneficiary.new(:quantity => 10, :gender => Gender.find_by_name('mujeres'), :beneficiary_type => BeneficiaryType.find_by_name('niños'))

    activity = Activity.new

    activity.beneficiaries << beneficiary_1
    activity.beneficiaries << beneficiary_2

    expect(activity.number_of_beneficiaries('hombres', 'adultos')).to eq 15
  end
end
```

That gives me.

> 1) Activity return number of beneficiaries by gender and type
>        Failure/Error: expect(activity.number_of_beneficiaries('hombres', 'adultos')).to eq 15
>
> ```
>    expected: 15
>         got: 10
>
>    (compared using ==)
>  # ./spec/models/activity_spec.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

The weird part is that if I invert the order in which I assign the beneficiaries it passes the test.

If I test for the expected number of beneficiaries, it correctly answers 2.

Comment: It seems like `if` statement is not working as expected. Is the code you provided the actual code (exactely how it is, i.e. ctrl+c, ctrl+v) or have you modified it in any way?

Comment: I only cut other methods/tests.

Comment: Ok, then we need to debug this. Try adding `p b' as your first line in your each loop (which btw is not ruby-like, we'll deal with it later) and paste the result of rspec.

Comment: I found the solution. I was doing something really stupid while loading the environments. The test database for gender was not being loaded appropiately. Because of this, the find_by_name in the creation of the beneficiaries was adding a nil as the gender. Somehow, that made the expect return the last thing declared. I don't know why (it should have been nil).

Comment: Ok, now about the rubiness of the code - please post this code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com if you want to improve the style (and, in this case, performance) of your code. :)